# Dramatic difference in network performance between multiple KVM virtual machines, accessing a bridged physical interface

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machine, bridge, linux-kvm

I have noticed a very peculiar difference in network speeds for the 3 VMs I have created. For one VM the network works without any issues. For the next the packet loss is between 50 and 100%, usually 75% (measured by sending 4 ping requests). The last is the worst - no ping comes through. Disabling the fist one does not seem to have any effect on the rest.

The Dell server, where my setup is, comes with 2 10gbps and 2 1gbps Ethernet ports. 3 out of 4 are connected and serve specific purpose:

- `eno1` (10gbps) - enslaved by my custom bridge, used for exposing the VMs to the local network of the company. Here all VMs are assigned an IP via the company's DHCP. Can also access the internet. It will be used (internally) for accessing a private cloud, a database and other project related things, all residing in their respective VMs
- `eno2` (10gbps) - static, directly connected for a data storage server that my server uses to dump data onto
- `eno3` (1gbps) - DHCP, used only for SSH administration of the host, can also access the internet (I would like to have redundancy in accessing online content, e.g. package for updating the host)

Beside the default `virbr0`, provided by the virtualization KVM/QEMU that uses NAT (192.168.122.x), I have setup another bridge that enslaves `eno1`:

```
bridges:
  br-kvm:
     interfaces:
     - eno1
```

The KVM configuration XML for it is

```
<network connections="3">
  <name>br-kvm</name>
  <uuid>****************</uuid>
  <forward mode="bridge"/>
  <bridge name="br-kvm"/>
</network>
```

The default `virbr0` has the following configuration XML:

```
<network connections="3">
  <name>default</name>
  <uuid>*****************</uuid>
  <forward mode="nat">
    <nat>
      <port start="1024" end="65535"/>
    </nat>
  </forward>
  <bridge name="virbr0" stp="on" delay="0"/>
  <mac address="52:54:00:3b:71:33"/>
  <ip address="192.168.122.1" netmask="255.255.255.0">
    <dhcp>
      <range start="192.168.122.2" end="192.168.122.254"/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
```

All of my VMs have two virtual NICs:

- NIC (default) - uses the default bridge, so NAT, will also be used for inter-VM networking (e.g. cloud service in one VM querying info from a database on another VM)
- NIC (ext) - uses my `eno1` bridge

All virtual NICs use the **virtio** driver.

The virtual machines are:

- VM1 - Ubuntu Server 22.04 with `microk8s` Kubernetes
- VM2 - Ubuntu Server 22.04 with PostGIS (PostgreSQL database with GIS extensions)
- VM3 - OpenSUSE Tumbleweed with KDE Plasma (used by a colleague of mine)

Out of all three, VM3 (OpenSUSE) is the one that has no network issues when accessed through the bridge.

VM2 suffers from packet loss (as mentioned above), while VM3 is completely "out" (at best 90+% packet loss), when it comes to the bridge connection.

I am using `netplan` for the Ubuntu Server VMs, for the OpenSUSE I used YaST (not really my goal to learn how to use SUSE).

The `netplan` YAML configuration for both problematic VMs is:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      dhcp4: true
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 10.22.1.2
        search:
        - my.company.com
    enp7s0:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

Here `enp1s0` is always the NATed default bridge, while `enp7s0` is the one tha uses my custom bridge.

At first I thought it's the configuration of the 2 VMs. And while yes, that might well be the case, I don't see how two VMs with same OS and same network configuration in regards to their NICs would exhibit such behaviour. I am no expert in virtualization and especially networking. In addition, while packets are dropped for VM2, the response time is the same as with VM1 (around 30ms).

I also tried (on the host) to play with various parameters of the custom bridge:

```
bridges:
    br-kvm:
      interfaces:
      - eno1
      parameters:
        stp: false
        ageing-time: 250
        forward-delay: true
        hello-time: 1
        max-age: 10
        priority: 10
```

I have read that the CPU can affect the network when it comes to virtual NICs when using the **virtio** driver since the NICs are actually connected to a virtual bus, residing in the RAM, so packet have to go through the RAM before landing at the physical NIC. This also has the advantage of inter-VM networking being extremely fast. In particular the single threaded performance is critical so the faster the RAM and CPU are, the faster an inter-VM will be. The server has two Intel Xeon E5-4650 v4, with the frequency going up to 2.8GHz so I'm hoping that all of that can provide enough speed when copying back and forth.

**UPDATE:**

I've noticed that in the GUI of virtual manager neither VMs with the problem had IPs for their respective NICs (those that are connected to my custom bridge):

**VM1 (severely crippled)**:

[image]

**VM2 (somewhat crippled)**:

[image]

**VM3 (ok)**:

[image]

Comment: Do all VMs have unique MAC addresses, IP addresses, and /etc/machine-id contents?

Comment: (As for "packet have to go through the RAM before landing at the physical NIC", that's generally true for _any_ type of virtual NIC – or even physical NIC, if RDMA/RoCE is not being used.)

Comment: Yes, all have unique MACs (although all start with `52:54:00:`, which I guess is something common for KVM?), IPs (the two groups of NICs - connected to the `virbr0` or my custom bridge - derive their IPs either from the KVM itself or from the DHCP, provided by the company) and machine IDs (check on all three the value `cat /etc/machine-id`).

Comment: I see people are casting votes to close due to "Needs more focus". Please, let me know what exactly makes you think there are multiple questions in my question. I am more than willing to provide information if I can get it.